# Minimal set of geometric moves in various equivalence classes of triangulated geometries

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, triangulations

I would like to get to know what is the minimal set of geometric changes "aka. moves" (topology preserving modifications / Pachner moves / bistellar moves) that can transform any 3-dimensional triangulations (with given constraints) into any other.

Under given constraints, I mean different equivalence classes of geometries.

The best way to discuss it is via the dual graph of the triangulation, where every node is a tetrahedron and every edge is a face.

> A: combinatorial triangulation: Every node is strictly 4-valent, and one can have only one dual-edge between nodes.

> B: relaxed (nondegenerate): there can be multiple connections between nodes, but every face and similarly every edge is defined by 3 different vertices. Similarly, a triangle is defined by 3 different edges and a tetrahedron is by 4 different triangles. There are no self-connections allowed in the dual graph.

> C: degenerate: allows for self-adjacency, nodes can connect back to themselves in the dual graph.

Taking the simplest case, the triangulation of S^3 from now on.

I assume, that a {1,4} and a {2,3} move can be enough to reach any geometric configurations in the case of A. Move {1,4} replaces a node with 4 half-dual-edges with 4 nodes that are fully connected except 1-1 remaining half-dual-edges. Move {2,3} exchanges two nodes that share a dual-edge (and have 3-3 half-dual-edges) with 3 fully connected nodes with 2-2 half-dual-edges each.

Case B is a bit more complicated, instead of move {1,4} let's use a {0,2} move, where a dual-edge between two nodes is replaced by 2 fully connected nodes (3 connections) plus 1-1 half-dual-edges. I thought, that these two moves should function, however, I couldn't yet figure out a simple situation:

Let's define a new move: take a loop in case B, cut it in half (introducing 4 half-dual-edges), place down 2 nodes with 2 connected dual-edges (thus 2-2 external ones), then connect one half of the loop to one and the other to the other node. This is a {0,2} move, but it is geometrically more involving.

In the simplest situation, imagine a graph of 2 maximally connected nodes (call it initial configuration). Performing this move turns this into a graph, which has 4 nodes, forming a circle with 2-2 dual-edges between each "adjacent" node.

> How can one reach this configuration without using the newly defined {0,2} geometric move?

Situation C is even more complicated, thus I would restrict my question to situation B only.

Comment: What about Pachner moves? Pachner, Udo (1991), "P.L. homeomorphic manifolds are equivalent by elementary shellings", European Journal of Combinatorics, 12 (2): 129–145, doi:10.1016/s0195-6698(13)80080-7

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand the paper (entirely). I'm not too familiar with abstract math, and it's hard for me to read it. I cannot find answer to my question in this paper.

Comment: Pachner moves are the answer to your concern in your first paragraph.  But do you mean something more specific when you ask for a "minimal" set?  Minimal in what sense?

Comment: I'm interested in specific moves for different manifold constraints (case A case B), as the minimal set of moves. In general Pachner are moves, which leave a boundary of a subset of a triangulation unchanged , while changing the interior. I gave examples of that specifically for different manifold constraints. I would be interested in a sequence of moves that reaches the configuration I specified from the initial one, without involving the particular move that directly brings that there. If it's possible, then that move is not "elementary" but composite, thus not part of the minimal set.

Comment: @Kregnach: You should try sending your question via email to Jaco and Rubinstein.  They likely have thoughts on most of your questions.

Comment: I considered doing so, just didn't know who to ask among many people, thank you for your recommendation!

Comment: You use "link" where I would write "edge" and you use "node" where I would write "vertex".  If you want to distinguish objects in the dual from objects in the primal (that is, original) then add the adjective "dual".  As in - "in the dual graph, all dual vertices have degree four" or "we require that dual edges meet two distinct dual vertices" and so on.

Comment: (I make this suggestion because "link" means something completely different in the context of combinatorial topology.)

Comment: I just meant a connection between two nodes of the dual graph (thus faces of the original triangulations), I got to know that the connection between vertices is "edges", but I don't know how to call the faces in the dual graph, so I called them links. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: Finally, this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.02806) gives work in the direction you desire.  If it does not answer your question, then you might reach out to the mathematicians mentioned in the abstract.

Comment: A face in the dual graph (dual to an edge in the primal) could be called a "dual face".

Comment: Why do you call so many things "links"?  Where is that language coming from?

Comment: Goodness.  And I suppose that an "external legs" is a half-edge.  I don't know what an "unclosed leg" is.

Comment: @Sam Nead , sorry, I need to get used to the proper jargon. In my group, we used to call edges links, as we didn't really care about the precise mathematical definitions but just wanted to use the fact, that a "link" as its name suggests, links two vertices. Now that I need to think about mathematical properties (like those in my previous questions), and as I'm asking mathematicians, I need to be more precise.

Comment: @SamNead the paper you suggested is really great and useful, thank you!